# Check if a substring contains a certain value

Tags: java

Is it possible to check if a substring contains a certain value and do something? I have this piece of code i'm wondering if I could check if **desc:** contains the value **\n** I have the config made with the following information

- test: desc:\ndog\ntest
- test2: desc:\ndog3

So how would I be able to retrieve the **\n** and loop through all the **\n** in that specific string list and do a action.

```
for (String s : plugin.file.getFile().getStringList(plugin.file.path))
{
    public void substring(){
    String labels = "item: desc:";

    String[] parts = labels.split(" ");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];
    System.out.println("Desc Value: " + s.substring(part2.length()).split(" ")[1])
   }
}
```

Comment: In your posted example `part2` is **always** "desc:'. How does this relate to your *test* `String`(s)? Also, your method has a `void` signature.

Comment: I know, i'm trying to learn how to do what I stated in the question. This is just a example.

Comment: That code edit you made won't compile. You can't declare a method inside a loop like that in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question in full but I think that you want something like this:

```
String test = "desc:\ndog\ntest";
String test1 = "desc:\ndog3";

String[] parts = test.split(":");
String name = parts[0];
String[] values = parts[1].trim().split("\n");
System.out.println("Name: " + name);
for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

You just split the values of [1] index in that parts table.